# How to display a UIWindow based dimmed background like UIAlertView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, background, uialertview, uiwindow

Here's my problem: I tried to display a UIWindow with a subview that displays a radial gradient. I wanted to put the window on the UIWindowLevelAlert. I had this all figured out before and it was working, but now I'm trying to reproduce it wasting hours...
This is the code I've got (the background is not a gradient because I wanted to keep it simple, then add a view that really is like the one of an UIAlertView):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
UIWindow *backgroundWindow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
backgroundWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
backgroundView.alpha = 0.5;
[backgroundWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
[backgroundWindow addSubview:backgroundView];
backgroundWindow.hidden = NO;
```

}

Comment: Declare UIWindow *backgroundWindow  in your .h file

Answer (score 4):

When a UIWindow is dealloc'd, it will be removed from the screen. Since you don't keep a reference to your UIWindow, I believe it is getting released and dealloc'd, and therefore it won't show.

The solution is to keep a reference to the window somewhere. Can you store it as a property in the class you're working in?

Comment: The UIWindow is not autoreleased before its added as a subview - even if release was called it wouldnt be released due to its retain count and the fact its not autoreleased, its a memory leak if anything.

Comment: The UIWindow will be released after the last line (in ARC, at least). The place to look is `[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows`. The created window will be there initially, but if you look at that array after a delay, that window will be gone.

Comment: but since we are at it, I thought that iOS apps generally only have one UIWindow, the app container window - shouldnt this be a view?  I have never tried to (or needed to ) show a UIWindow in an iOS app.

Comment: You can do some interesting things by using multiple UIWindows. For example, a UIAlertView uses a separate window. It helps to keep things separated, but it also can bring on some confusion.

Comment: yeah thats one thing Ive had to get used to building OSX apps is using NSWindowControllers instead of view controllers all the time.  But once you get the hang of it its easy.